# What is the shortest path that touches every tile in a square grid?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose a ant is placed on the position `(0,0)` of a chess-board. That ant wants to walk through every single tile of the board, while walking the least it can to do so. What path it must follow? Is there a formula `F(i)` that returns the position of the `ith` tile on that path?

Edit: as requested, I've tried the following:

1. I tried googling for keywords such as "shortest path", "shortest path in square grid", but couldn't find anything relevant.
2. I then downloaded, configured and used a Traveling Salesman Problem solver in a square grid. Obviously, the solution wasn't satisfactory, but I could gain an insight on the problem. There is an illustration of my results:
   [image]
3. I then, intuitively, speculated wether the answer could be something like the Hilbert Curve: [image]. I googled about it and asked on a IRC programming channel, but I couldn't find any actual evidence this is better than spirals and similars, nor a proof this is the best possible solution.

EDIT 2: Further clarifications:
The ant can move diagonally. The distance refers to the euclidean length of the line defined by the path.

Comment: 63 steps to walk on 64 squares? any path as long as no square is revisited

Comment: If it's a one-step for one grid, it's trivial: It has to be at least 63 (since one move can at best visit one new tile). Just walking across the bottom row, then up one row, across that one, and up at the end and so on does it in 63. So that works. As to many other paths

Comment: Everything I tried is on the edits now. I couldn't find any further information so I asked it here. It is, yes, a programming question since I am asking for an algorithm that solves a problem. Hope everything is clarified now.

Comment: No, it is still not a *programming* question. Where is your *code*? Questions simply asking for us to write you something are off-topic.

Comment: If, however, a grid has some finite size and so an ant can walk within a tile things are more complex.

Comment: It doesn't include a code because I do not know what is the proper algorithm, which is exactly what I am asking. I maintain my belief that this is a programming question, but you are free to disagree and express that as a closure vote. Thank you.

Comment: can the ant move diagonally?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a math problem

Comment: Note you don't ask for code, or an algorithm, but about paths and formulae for distance. It's a math problem, as asked, not a programming one.

Comment: You've still not said whether the ant can only move from one square directly to another or whether the squares have "size". It makes a fundamental difference to the algorithm

Comment: ... a formula is just a function. Which is a program. Well, Haskell hasn't done me a favor when asking SO questions, I guess. Just close it, then.

Comment: I do not think you ran your TSP solver correctly.

Comment: @tmyklebu I ran it wrong, indeed. Updated with the correct run. Much better!

Comment: OK.  Why isn't that solution satisfactory to you?

Comment: Same reason as the (3), but at this point I already understand any of those actually are equivalent, as Rafael pointed.

Answer (score 3):

Walk in straight line, with the edge of the board on your left, until you either hit the edge of the chess board or a tile you have visited before. If you do, then take a right.

Or a thousand other obvious patterns.

Any path that takes 63 steps is the minimum and just as good as any other path.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on if you're taking the width of each square into consideration or is this just a double array question?

If we're talking a double-array question f(x,y), then the answer is that there is no least path because the ant will need to travel to each square f(x,y) = x*y, so f(8,8) = 64.

If we start taking the width of the tiles themselves into consideration, then the answer is somewhat different because we can use some strategies to get the least amount of distance traveled (such as starting in the center, staying by the grid separators and walking in a roughly spiral pattern r=xy^(theta)).

Comment: `f(8,8) = 63`. Moving from the first square to the second means it's visited two squares, as it starts from 0,0.so starts having visited one.

Comment: depends. The path consists of edges and vertices. So its 64 vertices and 63 edges.